# Add dictionary values to dataframe column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With this dataframe `df`

```python
   a  b  c 
0  x  x  x
1  x  x  x
2  x  x  x
```

and this dictionary

```python
headers = {'a' : '3.14', 'b' : '6.67', 'c' : '8.31'}
```

`df = df.rename(headers)` allows to rename the column names as such

```python
   3.14  6.67  8.31 
0     x     x     x
1     x     x     x
2     x     x     x
```

How to just add the dictionary values to the column names? Like this:

```python
   a 3.14  b 6.67  c 8.31 
0       x       x       x
1       x       x       x
2       x       x       x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different lambda expression with f string,

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: f"{x} {headers[x]}")
```

Comment: That's nice! I think some brackets are missing though. Should read `"{x} {headers[x]}"`.

Comment: @macxpat good catch! it's fixed

Answer (score 1):

Try with `lambda`

```
df = df.rename(columns = lambda x : x + ' ' +  headers.get(x))
Out[613]: 
  a 3.14 b 6.67 c 8.31
0      x      x      x
1      x      x      x
2      x      x      x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new dictionary based on `headers`

```
df = df.rename(columns={col: f'{col} {num}' for col, num in headers.items()})
```

Output:

```
>>> df

  a 3.14 b 6.67 c 8.31
0      x      x      x
1      x      x      x
2      x      x      x
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not change the dict before,

```
headers = {'a' : '3.14', 'b' : '6.67', 'c' : '8.31'}

for key, value in headers.items():
    headers[key] = key + " " + value
    
print(headers)
```